# mod_wsgi 3.4 bug where 404 errors are misinterpreted

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, django-celery

In my django project using mod_wsgi 3.4 and apache, all 404 pages are not returned as a 404 error, but as a 500 server error:

When debug is set to true, it returns a 404 error, django's.

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    ..
No Model matches the given query.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Can anyone else who has experienced this problem before give some pointers or guides for fixing this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: So what does the server error log say?

Comment: I forgot the add the 500.html page, but this doesn't solve the issue because it was supposed to be a 404 page, the code uses the django get_object_or_404 shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is not a mod_wsgi bug.

Please make sure you have a `404.html` file in your 'templates' folder. If Django cannot locate a template for the 404 error, it serves up an Internal 500 error.

Note: If this doesn't solve the error, please take a look at [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view) on how to make a 404 error page work.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add a 500.html page, so after adding it it's loading the 500 page now, which still isn't correct because the code being used is the get_object_or_404 shortcut.

Comment: Do you have `Debug = True` set in your settings.py? If you make that change, please update your question with the error you see on that page.

Comment: When debug=True, I am getting the standard django 404 page.

Comment: Can you still copy/paste the error into the question? And if you're getting a 404 now, then it's hard to imagine why you'd get a 500 if you have a 404.html file in your templates folder.

Comment: This clearly identifies it as a 404 error. Please make take a look at the link in my answer. Also make sure the 404.html has proper permissions and is in the root of the templates folder.